# File not found exception occurred in python sub process checkout

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code 
when i run this it shows file not exception

---

import os,subprocess
import sys

Ip='127.0.0.1'
strsafemodestat13=subprocess.check_output(["fd --ip="+Ip+" --node=13", "reboot 2"])

---

can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs take arguments as a list. When you type a command like `fd --ip=127.0.0.1 --node=13`, your shell breaks those up into the 3 arguments `fd`, `ip=127.0.0.1`, and `--node=13`. Then it starts a process and hands it those three arguments.

The list that `subprocess.check_output` takes is actually a list of arguments for one command, not a list of commands. This might be closer to what you want:

```
import os,subprocess
import sys

Ip='127.0.0.1'
strsafemodestat13=subprocess.check_output(["fd", "--ip="+Ip, "--node=13"])
something_else=subprocess.check_output(["reboot", "2"])
```

Comment: actually i need to single command with multiple arguments. i used path as an argument eg.c:\data\release.zip changed as c:\\data\\release.zip .it throws problem